# Configuration of Gaomon M106K (equal to Huion New 1060 Plus) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, graphics-tablet

I've recently bought a Gaomon M106K graphics tablet and it runs fine in Ubuntu 20.04 out of the box, without any drivers, in Krita and Blender. But i don't know how to configure the keys on the tablet and the pen. I cannot assign the keys in Krita's keymap, so i guess there are no keys mapped by default.

The guides i found are mentioning xsetwacom to configure the keys, but "xsetwacom --list devices" doesn't return anything. Neither does the Wacom panel in the system settings.

"sudo evtest" lists both the tablet and the pen and reports all events. But i don't know which tool i could use to map these events to keypresses.

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but wich kernel are you using ? Don't know why, but mine is not working out of the box...

Answer (score 1):

I have a Gaomon m10 in Ubuntu 20.04 and I use the Digimend drivers.

To configure the buttons, use `xsetwacom` from the driver that is installed with digimend.

To find out if you are using that controller, with the tablet connected, open a terminal and type `xsetwacom list`.

Something like this should come out:

```
GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pen stylus id: 8 type: STYLUS
GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad id: 9 type: PAD
```

If so, you can configure the buttons using `xsetwacom` in terminal, but GNOME will only keep it for the session and it will be lost when turning off the PC.

To solve this, you can make a script and place it at startup to configure it on every power up of the PC.

This is the script I made:

```
!/bin/sh
pad

xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button  1 key Ctrl Shift I
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button  2 key Ctrl Shift A      
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button  3 key Ctrl A
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button  8 key Ctrl N
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button  9 key Ctrl Z
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button 10 key Ctrl X
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button 11 key Ctrl C
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button 12 key Ctrl V
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button 13 key Ctrl E
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button 14 key Ctrl Shift E
xsetwacom set "GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad pad" button 15 key Ctrl Y
```

Comment: Instead of using your own notation, in the future, you can use the [Markdown language](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format your posts.  If you're using the desktop version of AskUbuntu, you can also use the tools in the GUI immediately above the entry field where you would type a Question or Answer.